# fetching json with redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a issue with fetching json from server. When I'm trying to getState() from store there's "undefined" value.  I'm using "redux-thunk". Help!

Store and state:

```js
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const initialState = {
 datas: [],
 loading: false
};
```

Reducer:

```js
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
 switch(action.type){
  case FETCH_DATA_BEGIN:
  return {
   ...state,
   loading: true
  };
  case FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
   return {
   ...state,
   datas: action.payload.TableData
   }; 
  default:
   return state;
 };
}
```

Actions:

```js
function fetchData() {
 return dispatch => {
  dispatch(fetchDataBegin());
     return fetch("http://www.blblblblb.com")
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(json => {
         dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(json.TableData));
         return json.TableData;
       })
   };
}

const FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS';
const fetchDataSuccess = TableData => ({
 type: FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
 payload: {TableData}
});

const FETCH_DATA_BEGIN = 'FETCH_DATA_BEGIN';
const fetchDataBegin = () => ({
 type: FETCH_DATA_BEGIN
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: And the function/code to read from the state? tip: use the redux plugin to your browser and you can inspect whats actually is saved to the state for each action.

Comment: "I have a issue with fetching json from server." What is the issue? Give us a clue at least? Tell us what is happening and what you would like to happen.

Comment: sorry that's my first question. Can't figured out why my redux store won't get updated with data from server with fetch method, also when I'm trying to test it with store.getState() in console I'm getting empty list. In other hand, when I try to fetch data inside react component from the same server, in ComponentDidMount() works as expected. Need to use those data in other components